# Hardware required and Broadband for a Server with WHM to host 3 Magento Websites

Tags: server-setup

My name is Gabriel Bourgoing, Digital Marketing Consultant of WSI network.

I received a recommendation from my WSI Network as Magento Hosting Experts. I need obtain a quote from you and know the ideal Hardware (Servers)  that I o ensure the proper performance to host three  Websites developed in Magento in only one server with WHM

Please, let me know what hardware server specifications (Memory, bandwidth, etc) an the monthly cost.  Please send me the information to gbourgoing@wsiperformance.com

I can share with you the following information to determine the Server specifications and your quote

I have Three Websites in Magento (version. 1.9.2) which should be hosted three websites on only Server with WHM.

```
1)  Melody.com.mx
2)  Milano.com
3)  Home&Fashion.com (It is in  development)
```

I) TRAFIC BY WEBSITE

```
1)  Melody.com
a)  Number of visitors per month= 70,000 Sessions peak (December)
b)  Number of visitors real time= 12 Visitors Peak
c)  Number of database tables and records inside each site.=  Unknown, I only know that there is a  Table with 424 products x 53 Attributes. My understanding is that Magento has many tables
```

2) Milano.com
a)  I do not have Google Analytics to determine the visitors per month and visitors real time, but please take the same numbers of Melody.com.mx
Number of database tables and records inside each site.=  Unknown, I only know that there is a  Table with 579 products with 63 attributes each product. My understanding is that Magento has many tables, advise me

3) Home&Fashion.com 
a)  I do not have Google Analytics to determine the visitor s per month and visitors real time, but please take the same numbers of Melody.com.mx
Number of database tables and records inside each site.=  Unknown, I only know that there is a  Table with  100 products in the first upload  with 47 attributes each product. My understanding is that Magento has many tables, please, advise me

> II) RECORDS GET ADDED ON PER MONTH BASIS I can infer that the number
>   of Record added by website is the following
>
> ```
> Melody.com.mx    30 Products X 53 Attributes= 1590 records
> Milano.com.mx:     30 Products X 63 Attributes= 1890  records
> Home & Fashion 10 products X 47 Attributes=     480 Records
> Total per month= 3,960 records
> ```

III) FUNCTIONALITY USED IN  THE WEBSITES.

Products Catalog with functionality with  photos in 360 grades. In the future, only two website will be ecommerce. The three websites has pop up plug in.

IV)  HOW MUCH CPU LOAD REQUIRES TO RETRIEVE DATABASE RECORDS.

I do not how to obtain this information however; I am attaching the following information where the current websites are hosted.

```
Melody.com.mx
Memory Summary
Total Ram    Free Ram.   Total Virtual Memory    Free Virtual Memory       
3791 MB        2265           12,024 MB.             10,086 MB

Milano.com
Memory Summary
Total Ram    Free Ram.   Total Virtual Memory    Free Virtual Memory       
3832 MB        383           11,791 MB.             8,291 MB

Home&Fashion.com
Not available because is under construction.
```

VI) TRAFFIC GROWTH DO YOU EXCEPT IN NEXT 3, 6 AND 12 MONTHS.
For the next 3 month 100%, 6 Month 200%, and 12 Month 500%

Comment: we aren't going to know exactly how this will run.  It depends on extensions loaded and what you have completed.  It also depends on how many SKUs you have.  Although 70,000 peak per month is not that much info.  max in one hour is more useful.

Comment: all depends on your database size, but usually cPanel servers are really hungry on memory allocation.

Answer (score 4):

To share absolute numbers with you, hosting providers will ask you few questions in order to determine the perfect server configuration for a Magento store. These questions include:

- How will many unique visitors visit the stores daily?
- How many products, catalogs, the number of categories, attributes,
  attributes sets are there? What would be the future requirements?
- Do your stores provide any digital downloadable products?
- The total number of orders per day? (including pending, confirmed and
  canceled orders)
- Do you require any other feature like Varnish integration? Support
  for Memcached, Redis, Elasticsearch, etcetera?

Keeping all these above things in mind, on a rough note, I will recommend you to host your stores on cloud hosting servers rather than shared hosting. Cloud Hosting is reliable for Magento as it offers higher reliability and speed.

I work at [Cloudways](https://www.cloudways.com/en/), and we specialize in providing managed Magento cloud hosting servers that are specially optimized for Magento. The platform enables Magento developers and merchants to host their Magento 1 / Magento 2 stores easily on five different cloud hosting infrastructures i.e. DigitalOcean, Amazon AWS, Google GCE, Vultr, and Kyup.

You can visit our website and chat with one of our representatives. They will consult you further and get you the perfect match and best server plan for your Magento stores.